# Carrierwave file path stored in associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, carrierwave

My structure

```
class Project 
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :documents MyUploader

  def directory
    ...
  end

class Document
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :project
  mount_uploader :physical_doc

  def directory
    folder = File.join(self.project.directory, self.class::SUBFOLDER)
    Dir.mkdir(folder) unless File.exists?(folder)
    folder
  end

class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 def store_dir
    nil
  end

  def cache_dir
    self.model.directory
  end
```

The storage dir of my document is only known by the project (the location may change, and the `Project` class is responsible for moving docs in case)

**The problem**

When deleting a document, Rails will delete the "fields" in the order in which they appear in the code. That is to say

1. It will first delete the `:project` association
2. Then it will delete the `mount_uploader :physical_doc`
3. ... But the carrierwave mount_uploader needs to know where the file is stored in order to delete the file ! Oh oh.....

In other words, those two pieces of code are not equivalent

```
class Document
      mount_uploader :physical_doc
      belongs_to :project
      # This allows the document to be deleted, not created

class Document
      belongs_to :project
      mount_uploader :physical_doc
      # This allows the document to be created, not deleted
```

Solution ?

Comment: Maybe use `before_destroy` callback to actually remove the file while using the second code piece you posted?

Comment: Sorry, this dates back, but your solution works. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it. `before_destroy { attachment.file.destroy if attachment.file.exists? }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Adding my comment as an answer (I can use some points).*

Maybe use `before_destroy` callback to actually remove the file while using the second code piece you posted?

`before_destroy { attachment.file.destroy if attachment.file.exists? }`